# TypeScript Arrow function as return in another function in class return problem

Tags: typescript

look at this code.
When i look at console i have something like this:

```
() => {
            return this.msg;
        }
```

To be honest its wired for me.
One more thing. When i change return this.msg for console.log(this.msg) nothing happend in console. What ma i doing wrong?

```
class Problemo {
  msg: string = "hello"

  printFunction() {
    var vv = () => {
      return this.msg
    }

    return vv
  }
}

var pp = new Problemo()
var xx = pp.printFunction()

console.log(xx)
```

**@Solution.**
i forgot about brackets     `console.log(xx())`

Comment: What's the question? Everything works as expected, from what I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `printFunction` method declares a function `vv` that will print `this.msg` when called, so the value of `pp.printFunction()` will be a function, which you assign to `xx` and log to the console. That's why you see the source of the function:

```
console.log(xx) // outputs: () => { return this.msg; }
```

If you call `xx` instead, you will see the message:

```
console.log(xx()) // outputs: "hello"
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKBOB7ARiApgW0dA3gKGmgwgHMAuaCAF3gEsA7E6AXmgCIALNEERNvAtAAOdelQBiAV3rAqtRPQAUASlyDCANzDxoGjS2gqWAPjWFz0eGiqT49aFQ60IAOmIl10AL4CLVm3a6GoI%20PnhaOkJCBvRoAO5wSKiYiCrh2tAAHpkGUS4iDBLSsvJKygLAChCI6C68JIrZqgD0zdCIklRCnRAURsymOJbWtvaOzm6kANzeeJX01bX1jZkqLW0dXT0UnNy8-EA)

Comment: my bad i forgot about brackets. thank you!